# Docker shows service logs only after service update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We run our services in swarm mode. One of the services is an MQ subscriber instance of a Rails application. It receives messages **once a day** and processes them.

Docker version is 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

The problem is that there're no logs shown in the service logs until we manually restart service with "docker service  update --force". An assumption is that due to the inactivity the rest of the day it becomes "idle".

Here's the service config

```
service_1:
 image: ${MQ_SUBSCRIBER_DOCKER_IMAGE}
 environment:
  <<: *service_env
 command: 'bin/subscribe_to_mq'
 deploy:
  replicas: 1
  update_config:
    parallelism: 1
    delay: 3s
    failure_action: continue
    max_failure_ratio: 0.5
   restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
    delay: 30s
    max_attempts: 5
```

How can we somehow prevent service being "idle"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: STDOUT must be in sync mode

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the process of finding the cause of the issue and resolving it? I am having difficulties finding information regarding your answer and I am facing the same issue.